# Does dot product define a Riemannian metric on any smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The most natural example of a Riemannian manifold is $\mathbb R^n$ with the metric defined by $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$.

Can we generalize this simple dot product to a general smooth manifold $M$? Namely, define a metric by $\langle dx_q(e_i),dx_q(e_j)\rangle =\delta_{ij}$ where $x:U\rightarrow M$ is a parametrization at $q\in M$ and $dx_q$ is the differential of the map $x$ at $x^{-1}(q)$ (so it’s an abuse of notation).

Comment: Yes. To be more precise, you take a cover of $M$ by coordinate neighborhoods, do what you've outlined in each neighborhood, then use a partition of unity to glue all the local data and obtain a metric on the whole manifold.

Comment: I just noticed in a later part of my book that the same technique is used to show every manifold is Riemannian. Thanks @Aweygan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this does not work, because this definition is not independent of the parametrization chosen.  If you pick two different parametrizations $x:U\to M$ and $y:V\to M$ at the same point $q\in M$, they will usually define different metrics on the tangent space at $q$ (essentially because $dx_q^{-1}\circ dy_q$ will usually not preserve the dot product, since it could be any invertible linear map).

To get a well-defined metric on all of $M$ instead of just on one coordinate chart, you have to combine these "dot products" with a partition of unity.  Namely, take an open cover of $M$ by coordinate charts and use this "dot product metric" on each one, and then add them all up to get a metric on all of $M$ using a partition of unity subordinate to the cover.  This of course will be highly noncanonical since the resulting metric on $M$ you get depends on the choice of coordinate charts and partition of unity.

Comment: Yes exactly, it was my first exposure to an example of Riemannian manifold so my idea needed such an amendment